# Delete second line of text in every cell in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have an issue with Google Spreadsheets. I export bulk address lists from my eBay orders into Google Spreadsheet to be able to export as a CSV file to my label printer software for printing. The issue I have is eBay adds in a random string of text which look like this ebay:jlxjpd5 in between the name and address of each order. I don't want this text there and I have been manually deleting it from every order for a long time. I have attached a photo for reference of how the addresses look. Whenever I copy paste the address from eBay to Google Spreadsheet it is always in the format shown in the picture.

I know how to remove the word eBay and replace it with an empty space but then the random string of letters still appears. Basically I need a formula or method to be able to remove the second string/line of text/numbers in all cells or to remove 12 characters from the second string/line of text within each cell. In the below example I need all "ebay:hly9yhg, ebay:blypnh1, ebay:bly5rds" removed from the entire spreadsheet. The string of text after the word "eBay:" is random and changes for each order and is always 7 characters (12 characters including word eBay and colon). I deal with large amount of orders so deleting the words take up a lot of my time. If someone has a solution it will save me so much time so any help would be appreciated.

Note: The names and addresses are not real and made up for the sake of this question, no personal info has been revealed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this formula in B1:

```
=index(regexreplace(A1:A,"ebay:\w+\n",""))
```

[image: replace]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! I was wondering are you able to do a formula to keep the original spacing. example, Jacob T then the line underneath is empty and the 3rd and 4th line would be the address. The spacing between the name and address looks a lot better when I print out the name and address and also helps with the mailing machines to read the address.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out and was able to edit your formula to make it work. I ended up removing the \n and it keeps the original spacing. I used: =index(regexreplace(A1:A,"ebay:\w+","")) Thank you so much for helping me out. This is a lifesaver and will save me countless hours and hours of work

Comment: yes, the /n was used to eliminate the second line that became empty